# sinatra can't get data

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Sinatra Routes

```
get '/' do
  @tasks = Task.all
  slim :index
end

post '/' do
  Task.create params[:task]
  redirect '/'
end
```

INDEX

```
form action="/" method="POST"
  input type="text" name="task"
  input.button type="submit" value="New Task >>"
h2 My Tasks
ul.tasks
  @tasks.each do |task|
    li.task = task.name
```

Problem : `POST` succeeds, but get failed, I guess `Task.create` may have some problem, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Or is it that it does not work but you get no error message? How are you storing Tasks and can you post Task class structure as well?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need a `-`?

```
ul.tasks
  - @tasks.each do |task|
    li.task = task.name
```

Comment: It did have hyphen but during reformatting the question I missed it out. Sorry for the trouble.